# Voltage Drop/Sag - Current Limited Source

Tags: voltage-divider, current-source, voltage-measurement, current-limiting

I'm tinkering with the idea of adding a display for gear position on my motorcycle. It already has a gear position sensor that connects a different resistor in series to ground, depending on the gear that is selected. There is only a single wire out of the gear position sensor that connects to the ECU.

Given that all I have is these varied resistances to ground to indicate the selected gear:
[image: GPS resistance values]

**What is the best way to convert this to a voltage signal (0.1v to 5v) that the display (which is programmable for a voltage level in each gear) can use?**
(best being largely defined by being compact in physical size, reducing the amount of power consumed in the circuit, producing a stable voltage reading even if VCC varies or spikes, and being reliable even in vibration prone environment).

One way I can think of is to use a voltage divider with a fixed pullup (say 1200kohm, with Vcc of 5v from a 12v to 5v buck converter) and then tap the center point between that and the gear position sensor.

**Is there other ways of doing this though, for instance, can one use a nominal 5V current limited source (12v to 5v buck converter as above) and connect it directly to the GPS and just measure the sag at the voltage source output?**
**Is that a bad idea for some reason?**

I know the divider circuit would work, just curious how else this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: That's how I would do it. From there it would either be an MCU with built in A/D converter or a set of 7 comparators.

Comment: Make sure that the gear position sensor's cable is not connected to somewhere else --especially to a motor-control-related circuit. Because if it is then the external circuitry connected to this node may affect the behavior of the other block.

Comment: @RohatKılıç good point. I checked and within the wiring loom, it is not, it runs directly from the GPS to the ECU. What the connections look like inside the ECU though is another story. My guess is that it's most likely used within the ECU as an input decide when to retard ignition timing and/or fuel delivery when in lower gears. But, I can't be sure on that.

Comment: `it runs directly from the GPS to the ECU. What the connections look like inside the ECU though is another story.` So probably the ECU has its own measurement circuit inside. And if you connect an external pull-up for measurements then you may cause a fault on the ECU side. If possible, for each gear position, you may measure the **voltage** instead of the resistance seen from the GPS output while the engine is running. If you get stable voltages then you can fairly use that voltage through a voltage follower (buffer) so as to not to disturb the ECU. The rest is simple: MCU -> ADC -> Display.

Comment: @RohatKılıç to be honest I didn't actually check if there is a voltage on that line when running. Nothing with just the ignition on, but no reason for there to be. I'll have a look next week, might be the easiest solution of all.